# SQL Server Management Studio V18.6 does not show Actual Elapsed Time in Actual Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've updated SQL Server Management Studio to V18.6. Now i don't see the Actual Elapsed time in the Actual Execution Plan. The Estimated and Actual amount of rows with the operation cost is displayed, just the Actual Elapsed Time does not show.

I've searched through settings and tried to Google the problem, but until now i did not find a solution.

[MIssing Actual Elapsed Time Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vWw3.png)

I hope someone can help me to figure out how to make it show.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer: https://stack247.wordpress.com/2018/04/13/elapsed-time-of-each-operation-in-sql-server-execution-plan/#:~:text=In%20SQL%20Server%20Execution%20Plan%2C%20you%20can%20see%20actual%20time,show%20elapsed%20time%20in%20millisecond. or https://littlekendra.com/2016/12/20/actual-time-statistics-in-execution-plans-elapsed-cpu-time-and-more/

Comment: @KinchitDalwani I have seen this example, but this is not what i am looking for. Since V18 this is also shown in the Actual Execution plan with having to go through properties or to use live query statistics.

Comment: I still get the timings when using Live Statistics. Perhaps you don't have it enabled or you're running the query against a server that doesn't support Live Statistics? Older versions don't, for example, like 2012.

Comment: It seems it is indeed the version of the server that is the problem. One of the servers just got upgraded to a new version and now it does show in the Actual exectution plan.